# SalesForce Apex code fails on file download - Premature EOF

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

In my Apex code, I am trying to download a remote csv file to process in-memory.  Unfortunately, I am getting a `System.CalloutException: Premature EOF` error when I try to get the file.  I am able to connect to the server with the file (I can see the error messages returned when the file is not ready for download) so the connection details are likely not the problem.

```
private static void processURL(String url, UserHelper__c helper){

String username = 'login';
String password = 'password';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();

req.setEndpoint(url);

Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

req.setMethod('GET');

try {
    System.debug('processURL Send request: '+req);
    res = http.send(req); //Premature EOF hits here.
    System.debug('processURL successful');

} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    System.debug('processURL error: '+ e);
}

...

}
```

Comment: It may be that another Apex Class file that you reference is invalid. Have you done a 'Compile All Classes' from the 'Apex Classes" page recently to verify that any other Apex Classes that may be referenced from this file are valid? Other than that, perhaps the error is with the endpoint that's returning the file? Perhaps an invalid HTTP response is being handed back to Apex?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The Apex class is a stand-alone so there's no chance other classes are out of synch (also, it works properly when the server returns an error message instead of the file).  I am able to grab the returned file using a browser and the Poster plugin for FireFox, both without any visible issues, so I think that the HTTP response is valid.

Comment: How are you supplying creds with the browser? Do you have an endpoint that doesnt require authorization to test against?

Comment: Browser creds are given to the authorization popup in Chrome.  I do not have an end-point that does not require auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the server sending its response in a buffered manner.  It seems that the SalesForce Apex code cannot handle a buffered response.  I don't have all the details on what happened on the server-side so I cannot give more details than that.